# Битмап из буфера обмена

Tags: javascript, activex

Как при помощи ActiveX сохранить битмап из буфера обмена на клиентской машине?

Comment: А какой язык?

Comment: Желательно JavaScript, другое начальство не примет. То бишь вызываться всё из браузера должно.

Answer (score 1):

Если уже есть готовый ActiveX на примете, то надо представить его API. Если нужно написать свой ActiveX с нуля, то API работы с изображениями [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041(v=vs.85).aspx-) поможет. Что-то вроде:

- GdiplusStartup
- GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP
- GdipSaveImageToFile
- GdipDisposeImage
- GdiplusShutdown

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вопрос про `ActiveX`, то, видимо, речь идет про `Internet Explorer` и `Windows`. Можно проверить такой способ:

1. получить картинку из буфера обмена с помощью метода getData объекта [clipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535220(VS.85).aspx);
2. преобразовать в нужный формат;
3. сохранить картинку в файл с помощью метода SaveToFile объекта ActiveX [ADODB.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(v=vs.85).aspx).